# How to append data to specific post using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Summary:

I have a list of posts, each post also containing a list of comments within it. I have the option to add a comment directly on the post (much like twitter). I submit those posts via ajax.

Problem:

When submitting a new comment, is updates all the "comments lists" of each and all posts, and not only the one I have submitted from.

Any ideas? (code below)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        //clearForm: true,
        //resetForm: true,
        //beforeSubmit: ShowRequest,
        success: function (html) {
            $('.post_comment_list').prepend(html);

            $('.footer-post').hide();
            $('.comments-feed').hide();
            $('.small-textarea-main-feed').removeClass('set-large');
            resetForm($('.footer-comment'));
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('ERROR: unable to upload files');
        },
        complete: function () {

        },
    };

    $(".footer-comment").ajaxForm(options);

    function ShowRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
        var queryString = $.param(formData);
        alert('BeforeSend method: \n\nAbout to submit: \n\n' + queryString);
        return true;
    }

    function resetForm($form) {
        $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
        $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox')
            .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
    }
});
```

PHP

```
       <?php 
     if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
      //register user
         $post_comment = array(
        'comment'      => $_POST['comment'],
        'id'      => $_POST['id'],
         );


        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        post_comment_db($user_id, $post_comment);
        //print_r($post_question['tags']);
        load_comment($user_id,$post_comment);



        } else{
          echo output_errors($errors);
         }
           ?>
```

PHP/HTML: Li (the comment to be added)

```
            function load_comment($user_id,$post_comment){


          $username = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"), 0, 'username');
          $timestamp = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `timestamp` FROM `comments` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"), 0, 'timestamp');
           $r = format_time($timestamp);

          $question_id = $post_comment['id'];

           $q = "SELECT `comment_id` FROM `question_has_comments` WHERE `question_id` = $question_id ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1" ;
           $q = "SELECT `comment_id` FROM `comments` WHERE `question_id` = $question_id ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1" ;


          echo 
           '                
    <li id="" class="post_comment">                                     
        <!--  wrapper da imagem -->
        <div id="" class="give-margin">
            <div id="" class="profile-page-avatar-wrapper"> 
                <a href="#"><img id="" class="profile-page-avatar-image" src="./images/test/chemistry.jpg" alt=""></a><!--  A imagem -->
            </div>
            <!--  o botao e o texto-->

            <div id="" class="profile-page-uploader-tools"> 
                <!--  o botao -->
                <div id="" class="profile-image-btn">
                    <div id="" class="profile-page-btn-wrapper">
                        <div id="" class="header-id">
                            <a href="#"><span id="user-name">' . $username . '</span></a>   
                        </div>
                        <div id="" class="question-page-feed-answer-header-timer">
                            <a id="feed-answer-header-timer" href="#"><span class="timer" data-time="">' . $r . '</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- fecha Div wrapper do botao-->
                </div> 
                <!--  fecha botao 
                http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/Overview.html#toc-->
                <p>' . $post_comment['comment'] . '</p>
            </div>                                  
        </div>
    </li>';
```

}

Comment: It would probably help to see the HTML that goes along with this.

Comment: What is a post? If you mean `POST` then there is no way for the browser to know of other `POST` messages going on to the server.

Comment: A post with be the same as a tweet. A tweet may have its comments and you have a tweet feed (many tweets). It is the same. I want to submit a comment on one of my "tweets" and it updates that comments on all tweets comments list.

Comment: ajaxForm is the Jquery Form plugin. I'll add the php.

Comment: What are your reasons for using the .ajaxForm plugin? If using this plugin because you are inexperienced with ajax, are you willing to dump it if we can help you solve the problem without it? (AJAX is much simpler than many imagine; plugins are usually unnecessary and only inoculate the programmer from mastering a simple but useful skill)

Comment: Please show your HTML that surrounds the element(s?) with `class="post_comment_list"`. Is it possible that there are more than one element with this class?

Comment: Hi Gibberish. Regarding ajax, for other things I manipulate the ajax as usual though I had some complications making it work with input[type:file] so ajaxForm worked just fine. Nevertheless, of course I am open to new implementations, those are welcome. Lastly, the class "post_coment_list" is an "ol" present in all posts, where the comments to a post reside.

Comment: I posted (what I hope will be) a solution. If my answer helps you, please upvote it and remember to also choose a correct answer to close the question (both are possible, if desired).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last comment response identified the problem:

`the class "post_coment_list" is an "ol" present in all posts, where the comments to a post reside`

From the api:

**.prepend():**  [Description](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/): Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each element *in the set of matched elements.*

In your code, the ajax success function prepends the returned HTML as follows:

```
$('.post_comment_list').prepend(html);
```

Since `$('.post_comment_list')` is a set of all elements with class `.post_comment_list`, and since every post has that class, your HTML will be prepended to each and every post.

To solve this, assign each post a unique ID and, in the success function, prepend the HTML only to that one ID.

To get that ID, you can grab it at the time the ajax call is made and either:

1. assign the ID to a global var and grab it again in the success fn, or
2. send the ID along with the other ajax data, and then send it back to the success fn along with the HTML. For example:

**PHP side:**

```
$post_id = $_POST['postid'];

$send_back = $post_id . '|' . '<li id="" class="post_comment">                                     
    <!--  wrapper da imagem -->
    <div id="" class="give-margin">
    etc
    ';
echo $send_back
```

**jQuery/javascript:**  (inside success: function)

```
    var arrHTML = html.split('|');
    var postId = arrHTML[0];
    var html_code = arrHTML[1];

    $('#'+postId).prepend(html_code);
```

---

Note that, above, I did not demonstrate sending the post ID over to the PHP side. I'm sure you are alright with that. Just showed enough to explain what I was suggesting.

Comment: Gibberish, thanks for the tip! One thing, I had to had $.trim(arrHTML[0]); because is was giving me a huge empty string. Could you help me out with other thing: the comment is prepended correctly (now to the post I am targeting) though it only does that once I put the first comment and reload the page. If the comments-ol is empty, it doesn't prepend. Any idea why that might be happening?